# How do I match one string from a set of strings, followed by some digits, followed by another string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of files with names like this:

```
01990205abc.dat
20200304abc.dat
20210506abc.csv
```

My goal is to match the last two strings, but not the first string. I used this pattern: `^(2020)|(2021)[0-9]{4}abc.(csv)|(dat)$` and this code:

```
files <- list.files(path = "mirror", pattern = "^(2020)|(2021)[0-9]{4}abc.(csv)|(dat)$")
print(files)
```

matches all three files, instead of just the last two. My expectation was that

- `(2020)|(2021)` would match one of the years, but not `0199`.
- `[0-9]{4}` would match exactly four digits, then `abc`, followed by one or the other file extensions.

Comment: You misplaced the groups. It should be `"^(2020|2021)[0-9]{4}abc\\.(csv|dat)$"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the pattern

```
^202[01][0-9]{4}abc\.(?:dat|csv)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XICVK/1)

With the doubled escaped dot and capture groups:

```
^(202[01])[0-9]{4}abc\\.(dat|csv)$
```

- `^(202[01])` Start of string and capture 2020 or 2021
- `[0-9]{4}abc` Match 4 digits 0-9 and `abc`
- `\\.` Match a dot
- `(dat|csv)` Capture either dat or csv
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mGlfY3/1/)